# didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath - is always returning the previous selection

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a UITableView, a custom class for the custom cell and my ViewController swift:

```
private var model_firma = [Firme]()
var firme = Firme(IDFirma: 1, Denumire: "ZZZZZ", Reprezentant: "JohnDoe")
    model_firma.append(firme);
    firme = Firme(IDFirma: 2, Denumire: "YYYYYYY", Reprezentant: "JohnDoe")
    model_firma.append(firme);
```

And:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return model_firma.count
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! FirmeTableViewCell
        let item = cell.labelDenumire
        labelSelectedCompany.text = item?.text
}
```

The items are displayed correctly.
But, at the first click on the tableview, on any item, nothing happen. At the second click || selection on a different item, the previous item is retrieved.

The function I use to add rows to the UITableView using the data from the model :

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! FirmeTableViewCell
let text = model_firma[indexPath.row]

cell.labelDenumire.textColor = UIColor(rgb: 0xffffff)
cell.labelDenumire.text = text.Denumire
```

It seems that I can't figure it out by my myself.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why are you taking the reference of the cell and then taking the value from the label's text why not taking the value directly from the array?

Comment: The same behavior happens, I get the value in this way for debugging purposes.

Comment: 1. First I select the company "ZZZZZ", NOTHING happens.

2. Then I select the company name "YYYYYYY". I click the company "YYYYYYY" I get the previously selected "ZZZZZZ"... etc etc etc

Allways I get the previous selected item, not the actual selected item.

Comment: Is the code in your question your real, actual code, copied and pasted into your question? The behavior you describe sounds like you mistakenly implemented `didDeselectRowAt` in your code. But what you posted correctly shows `didSelectRowAt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically, in the `didSelectRowAt` I would assume that you should read the desired data from the the data source (`model_firma`) directly instead of getting the cell and read from it:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let currentModel = model_firma[indexPath.row]
    labelSelectedCompany.text = currentModel.Denumire
}
```

---

**Sidebar Notes:**

- In Swift, we usually follow the *camel case* naming convention:

  - `modelFirma` instead of `model_firma`.
  - variable names should start with a *small letter*: `denumire` instead of `Denumire`.

Instead of:

```
private var model_firma = [Firme]()
var firme = Firme(IDFirma: 1, Denumire: "ZZZZZ", Reprezentant: "JohnDoe")
    model_firma.append(firme);
    firme = Firme(IDFirma: 2, Denumire: "YYYYYYY", Reprezentant: "JohnDoe")
    model_firma.append(firme);
```

preferably, it should be as:

```
private var firmes = [Firme(IDFirma: 1, Denumire: "ZZZZZ", Reprezentant: "JohnDoe"),
                      Firme(IDFirma: 2, Denumire: "YYYYYYY", Reprezentant: "JohnDoe")]
```

with removing the `;`.

Comment: Thank your for the tips!

Comment: @OvidiuMuntean are you sure that `model_firma` is not been editing or something? try to debug what is happening in the `didSelectRowAt` method.

Comment: Ahmad, THANK YOU!

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let currentModel = model_firma[indexPath.row]
    labelSelectedCompany.text = currentModel.Denumire
}

IS WORKING as expected!